# Sum an ever increasing number of rows until a specific min/max value is exceeded

Tags: r

I'm using data table and have one column which contains either a number or NA. Starting with row 1, I want to sum the column by adding the minimum number of rows until a specific value is met or exceeded, or it encounters NA. It should then start again at row 2, repeating for each row. Once it has passed an NA as the new start position, it can continue to the next NA.

The returned value should be the sum or NA if neither targets were reached.

The range of numbers can be anything, but are mostly -1, 0 and 1.

I've written a function but it's dog slow over 4 million rows. Is there a way I can do this quicker ? I'll want to vary the PosMax and NegMax variables.

Thanks for the help.

```
z <- c(1, 1, NA, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1 ,1, -1, 0 ,0 ,0, 1)
FindMovement(z, 2, -1)
  [1]  2 NA NA  2 -1 NA NA NA -1  2 NA -1 NA NA NA NA
```

Function is:

```
FindMovement <- function(Change.Col, PosMax, NegMax) {
  y <- NULL
  x <- Change.Col
  for(m in 1:length(x)) {
    y[m] <- 0
    if (x[m] != 0 & !is.na(x[m])) { 
      for (n in m:length(x)) {
        if(is.na(x[n])) { break }
        y[m] <- sum(x[m:n])
        if (y[m] >= PosMax | y[m] <= NegMax) {
          break
        }
      }
    }
  if (y[m] < PosMax & y[m] > NegMax) { y[m] <- NA }
  }
  return(y)
}
```

**EDIT :** Apologies for the confusion. If the start number is zero, the result should be NA.

To clarify, with z <- c(1, 1, NA, 2, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1 ,1, -1, 0 ,0 ,0, 1) we would get :

```
Position  1:  1 + 1 = 2 (PosMax)
Position  2:  1 + NA = NA
Position  3:  NA = NA
Position  4:  2 = 2
Position  5: -1 = -1 (NegMax)
Position  6:  0 = NA 
Position  7:  0 = NA
Position  8:  0 = NA
Position  9: -1 = -1
Position 10:  1 + 1 = 2
Position 11:  1 + -1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = NA (Target not reached)
Position 12: -1 = -1
Position 13:  0 = NA
Position 14:  0 = NA
Position 15:  0 = NA
Position 16:  1 = NA
```

Comment: I've read the first paragraph a few times, and I can't see how that description matches up to the output from your `FindMovement` function.  Please can you edit your question to talk us through how it works.

Comment: it wouldn't be difficult to recode that function in c and run it using the `inline` package

Answer (score 0):

Try this, can't test performance right now, but it should be faster:

```
z.mat <- matrix(rep(z, length(z)), ncol=length(z))
# zero out prior values for each col
z.mat[upper.tri(z.mat)] <- 0
# get a cumsum of each column
z.mat.sum <- apply(z.mat, 2, cumsum)
# add condition that if series starts with 0, should be NA
diag(z.mat.sum)[diag(z.mat.sum) == 0] <- NA
# get the first of -1, 2, or NA in the cumsum
result <- apply(z.mat.sum, 2, function(x) x[which.max(x %in% c(-1, 2, NA))])
# for columns that didn't get to a target, you'll get 0, so replace these with NA
result[result == 0] <- NA
result
# [1]  2 NA NA  2 -1 NA NA NA -1  2 NA -1 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly (despite me moving the goalposts) except it runs out of memory when I try to apply it to a set of 4 million numbers.

Comment: You could split the vector at the `NA`s and process each part individually, then combine the results.